# What's the acceptable bend in a typical faucet flex pipe?

Tags: water, faucet, sink

I installed new faucets and used the standard flexible lines for the water connections. I purchased 12 inch lines since the distance between the faucet and the valve is slightly less than 12, but when I installed them, the shorter distance caused a fairly tight bend in the middle and where the mesh meets the connector:

[image]

There doesn't seem to be any problems.. yet, but I am concerned about long term wear from having it in this configuration. For this reason, I was going to replace the 12 inch lines for the longest available so I can make a loop, like this:

[image]

I wasn't sure, however, if this configuration is actually better since I don't know what kind of bend these things can handle in a practical scenario and whether it is better to have the bend in the pipe, or at the connector. When searching online, most of the information I found simply recommended doing a custom bent steel line if the distance or angle is awkward, but I would rather just take the simpler approach if possible.

Does my first configuration have too much bend in the pipe, and if so, is the looped configuration a better alternative?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The loop would be more for copper tubing.

Comment: I always buy longer and loop, to prevent stress at the crimped and threaded connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks fine. If it concerns you then you can loosen the compression nut on the valve and rotate the orientation of the valve until you have a more gradual bend in the hose.

Comment: Thank you for the simple, yet effective solution, I was being a little lazy with not wanting to turn off the main water, but that was most certainly a good approach.